# How do I modify the connection habits of my Kindle Keyboard 3G?

Tags: kindle, wifi, 3g

I have Kindle Keyboard 3G, I use the text to speech for reading books while commuting.  If I leave the wireless turned on it uses up the battery pretty fast trying to keep and or find a 3G  or WiFi connection.

I would like to modify the behavior so it does not try and use the 3G and only checks for WiFi once an hour or so.  If it does not find WiFi it should wait an hour before trying again.

[Per Kindle Help](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201176040)

> Your Kindle automatically turns 3G coverage off when you connect using Wi-Fi. When you disconnect from a Wi-Fi network or if you move out of Wi-Fi range, your Kindle automatically switches back to 3G coverage.
>
> For Kindle models that include free 3G, wireless connectivity is automatic (with no monthly fees or annual contracts). If you see one of the 3G network indicators (3G, EDGE, or GPRS) in the upper right corner of your Kindle screen, your Kindle is already connected wirelessly using 3G.

The general help does not seem to include any directions for modifying the wireless habits.  A solution that does NOT permanently disable the 3G would be preferable.

Comment: I think you can temporarily disable all connectivity by setting airplane mode. You could then turn it on only when you knew you had WiFi coverage. This doesn't answer the question though...

Comment: Yes; you can turn the wireless on and off, pretty easy.  But then you have to remember to do it as you are coming home and leaving for work.  Having the WiFi on when home is not a big battery drain.  It is having the wireless on all the rest of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into this since you posted this and it's just not possible. Well, if you want to completely replace the existing OS and software, you could, but that doesn't really address your use case.